# Removing solr.PorterStemFilterFactory from Solr fieldtype filter causes Highlighting error

Tags: solr, coldfusion

In a ColdFusion site using Solr for searches, I am trying to edit the schema.xml file so that stemming is turned off and only exact word matches are returned. This is how the fieldType is defined for text:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I removed the analyzer node, restarted the core handling this particular search and get the following exception message: "Element HIGHLIGHTINGRESULT is undefined in CFML structure referenced as part of an exception."

In the results page, the word matches are highlighted. The page results are rendered in the following field:

```
<field name="body" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

I changed the type in the body field to "string" and got the same error. When I took the solr.PorterStemFilterFactory filter out of the text fieldType, the result page looks OK as long as the item has an exact match. When an item with stemmed match is found (ie. the word searched is "guard" and an item is found with "guarded"), the exception is thrown.

I've come across a number of different ways to set the fieldType to only return an exact match, but this issue with the highlighting is one that has me stumped.

UPDATE: I have found that not only are found words highlighted in the text displayed, but if they are found in HTML tags, the page renderer tries to wrap it in a  tag. So, for the word "lepers", an  tag with "lepers" in the title gets this, breaking the tag:
[image: broken tag]

Comment: Have you tried using the `text_exact` field type? I think that is one of the standard types installed by CF (at least it was as of CF 9). It does tokenizing a bit differently: `<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>`.

Comment: Also, I assume from your highlighting issues that the HTML tags are actually part of the indexed field? Or does CF not use Solr highlighting?

Comment: David, I'm going to give your suggestion on the text_exact field type a try. I'm a newbie at Solr, though I've done CF for quite some time. We had a conference call with the developer who put this together (but doesn't have time to fix it). It does look like he didn't use Solr's highlighting. There's no reason CF can't use it, so I'll look at that as well.

Comment: So, I tried using the text_exact field type, and got the same problem with the highlighter breaking the search results page as indicated above. For some reason, the highlighter seems to want to look for stemmed search results, even when the field is only looking for the exact term. I did look in the config file for the core being used and the output page IS using Solr's highlighting feature.

Comment: if you could reproduce the code from the output page I might be able to help.

Comment: I've handed this project back to the original developer. He has elected to point the search to a text-only version of the content, avoiding the HTML tag issue.